# Why is push shown as undefined, even though it is a keyword and i have not declared this as any object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
  if (prop !== "tracks" && value !== ""){
    collection[id][prop] = value;
  }


  if (collection[id].hasOwnProperty("tracks") == true){
    if (value === ""){
      delete collection[id].prop;
    }
    else{
      collection[id].tracks.push(value);
    }
  }

  if (prop === "tracks" && collection[id].hasOwnProperty(prop) == false){
    collection.prop = [];
    collection[id].prop.push(value);


  }



  return collection;
}
```

So the function should add new values to the arrays, but I am not sure why i keep getting an error saying it is push of undefined.

Comment: First, `push` is not a "keyword"; it's just a method name. Your error means that the thing to the *left* of `.push()` is `undefined`.

Comment: Note that your code adds a `.prop` property to `collection`, but then references `collection[id].prop` instead.

Comment: You've to use the bracket notation consistently when the property name is stored in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to push something to  `collection[id].prop`?

You must have left out the index reference for `collection` at the previous line:

```
collection[id].prop = [];
```

Comment: oh how did i miss that! Thank you so much